# How to check if a date is before or after a locale time

Tags: javascript, date, time, momentjs, date-nfs

I am working on a locale news application.

Readers will get the news close to their place if you are in Paris, your local time zone is `Europe/Paris`, and we release news at 9am every morning.

We want to allow `before 9am` publishing

*How can I check if `9am Europe/Paris` is after or equal to `new Date()` (no matter what the client zone is) in `JavaScript`?*

- *In this end I will add an offset of -1hours, to block news posting at 8am*
- *we already have that check server side, it's mainly for alerting the user that it will posted the next day*

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with multiple time zones. You should always compare in UTC (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours). The idea is

1. Use "new Date('August 19, 1975 09:00:00 GMT+01:00');" to create a current time in Paris timezone.
2. Then use "date.getUTCHours();" to get hours in UTC
3. Then compare this value to client timezone hours (in UTC).

```js
var parisTime = new Date('March 20, 2020 09:00:00 GMT+01:00');
var parisInUTC = parisTime.getUTCHours();

var ukTime = new Date();
var ukInUTC = ukTime.getUTCHours();

console.log(parisTime);
console.log(parisInUTC);
console.log(ukTime);
console.log(ukInUTC);
console.log(ukInUTC < parisInUTC);
```

Comment: Yes but I have as input arguments `timeZone = "Europe/Paris"` and `timeZoneReleaseHour = 9`, the `9` correspond to `9am` paris, I don't even know how to initiate this UTC

Comment: You can create new Paris time by using new Date('August 19, 1975 23:15:30 GMT+07:00');

Comment: How do I get `August 19, 1975 09:00:00 GMT+01:00` starting from the provided date, it should be the same date (not locale date), eg 2020-01-01 05:00:+07:00 should also be 2020-01-01 09:00:+01:00

Comment: From your database, you should be able to tell at what time the news is created? What value do you have?

Comment: I have tried `const todayPublishDate = new Date(value.getFullYear(), value.getMonth(), value.getDate(), timeZoneReleaseHour, 0, 0, 0);` but it gives me `Sat Mar 21 2020 09:00:00 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time)`

Comment: what is todayPublishDate? I thought you want to compare Paris 9AM with current client Time?

Comment: todayPublishDate  is the publishing date offered to the user client side, if we are now after 9am today, then next publish date is tomorrow 9am (again paris time)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210013/discussion-between-dimitri-kopriwa-and-alex-tin-le).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)

```
moment.tz("09:00","HH:mm","Europe/Paris").isSameOrAfter(new Date())
```

Comment: Thanks, can I just use `9:00` in case it's 10 I don't want to have a leading 0

Comment: you can but then you need to write `hh:mm` as the second argument

Comment: I have tested and `isAfter Fri Mar 20 2020 17:11:07 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time)`, while 9am GMT+1 of the same day is Before